# What should I use for a box for a game? ANDROID

Tags: android

Just got started with android development. I want to create a simple game and need something like a box, the equivalent of a container in HTML. This box needs to ofcourse be clickable. I can't find anything like this. What is it that I'm looking for? Thanks!

To clarify:

What do I type inside of the xml file in android studio to display this box I'm talking about?

Comment: What game framework are you using? Unity? libgdx? [Something else](http://siliconangle.com/blog/2015/07/30/an-updated-list-of-the-best-android-developer-tools-for-your-amazing-mobile-game/)?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know if android studio is a framework but that's what I'm using. If "android studio" is not the answer you are looking for then please clariy. Remember I'm an extreme newbie when it come to android development and I really have no idea what is going on. Thanks

Comment: Any view or a class derived from view can implement onTouchListener (thus becoming receptive of clicks). What exactly is the point of that box? I mean, you can make a bloody rectangle and make it clickable :D

Comment: The problem is, I'm to much of a noob to know how to make that bloody rectangle.